# Brushing data on plot linked with 2D variable

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 2D numeric array (100x100 double) which looks like this when plotted on a surf plot:

[image]

I am trying to link the plot with the variable, and then delete some data points (say, one of the two peaks) both in the variable (make the selected points 0) and in the plot, by using the brush tool on the plot.

The problem is, when the variable and the plot are linked, the brushing tool selects the full rows for the points that fall on the selected area, as shown here:

Selection when data is linked (I want to avoid this type of selection):

[image]

Same selection, data not linked (this is what I want, but with linked data):

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this, and select only the points that I want?

Details about this phenomenon can be found here:
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.interaction.internal.brush.html#mw_b080675e-afd3-4251-99d8-a8273e85dc6c

I have also tried using other types of plots (mesh, sky, etc), but I could not find any solutions.

As a minimal reproducible example, you can use the following code:

```
PeaksVariable = peaks;
surf(PeaksVariable)
linkdata on
brush on
```

Comment: How to do intend to "delete" the data if not deleting the entire row/column? You can't have a hole in your matrix... do you want to end up with NaN there?

Comment: Hello @Wolfie, when I use the brush tool to delete data it replaces them with NaN. I would ideally like them to be 0, but I suppose I can convert NaNs to 0's later on. Could you elaborate on why I can't have a hole on the matrix?

Comment: I just meant you can't literally have missing data, the matrix has to contain _something_ in every element, NaN or 0 is fine. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], i.e. code to let us create a simple plot with data linked in the same way you're doing it, so we might advise how to improve the code

Comment: Thank you very much for the information @Wolfie, I'm quite a newbie as you can probably tell. I have added a simple example to the post as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the brushed data points with

```
PeaksVariable = peaks;
brush on;
s = surf( PeaksVariable );
b = logical( s.BrushData );
```

Then set the brushed points to whatever value you want

```
PeaksVariable( b ) = NaN;
```

And optionally update the surface with the updated data variable

```
s.ZData = PeaksVariable;
```

[image: brushed]

[image: removed]