# Interactive plot to change array values (MATLAB)

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, multidimensional-array, interactive

```
N = 500;
pattern = zeros(N,N);

grid on
plot(pattern)
% gets coordinates of modified cells
[x,y] = ginput;
% convert coordinates to integers
X = uint8(x);
Y = uint8(y);
% convert (X,Y) into linear indices
indx = sub2ind([N,N],x,y);
% switch desired cells on (value of 1)
pattern(indx) = 1;
```

I'm trying to assign several elements of a zeros array the value of 1. Basically I want to create an interactive plot where the user decides what cells he wants to turn on and then save his drawing as a matrix. In Python it's very simple to use the `on_click` with *Matplotlib*, but **Matlab** is weird and I can't find a clear answer. What's annoying is you can't see where you clicked until you save your changes and check the final matrix. You also can't erase a point if you made a mistake.

Moreover I get the following error : `Error using sub2ind Out of range subscript. Error in createPattern (line 12) indx = sub2ind([N,N],X,Y);`

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to use the brush tool? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72213186/brushing-data-on-plot-linked-with-2d-variable

Comment: @Wolfie The brush tool doesn't seem to be what I am looking for. It's useful to select a rectangular area. But I want to be able to click on a specific point to update his data.

Comment: Your error is indeed baffling. `x,y,` can't be more than 256, because you force them to be `uint8`, yet `N` is 500. Can you show us teh values of when this errors?

Comment: You can click (rather than click and drag) with the brush tool and it will pick the same point the data cursor would... alternatively you can do something similar with the data cursor tool https://stackoverflow.com/a/22141863/3978545

Comment: I found this [link](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/495749-capturing-mouse-clicks-on-an-array-patch#answer_427769). But I can't get to switch a on cell to off for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CreatePattern
    hFigure = figure;
    hAxes = axes;
    axis equal;
    axis off;
    hold on;
    N = 3; % for line width
    M = 20; % board size
    squareEdgeSize = 5;

    % create the board of patch objects
    hPatchObjects = zeros(M,M);
    for j = M:-1:1
        for k = 1:M
            hPatchObjects(M - j+ 1, k) = rectangle('Position', [k*squareEdgeSize,j*squareEdgeSize,squareEdgeSize,squareEdgeSize], 'FaceColor', [0 0 0],...
                'EdgeColor', 'w', 'LineWidth', N, 'HitTest', 'on', 'ButtonDownFcn', {@OnPatchPressedCallback, M - j+ 1, k});
        end
    end

    
    Board = zeros(M,M);
    playerColours = [1 1 1; 0 0 0];
    
    xlim([squareEdgeSize M*squareEdgeSize]);
    ylim([squareEdgeSize M*squareEdgeSize]);
    
    function OnPatchPressedCallback(hObject, eventdata, rowIndex, colIndex)
        % change FaceColor to player colour
        value = Board(rowIndex,colIndex);
        if value == 1
            set(hObject, 'FaceColor', playerColours(2, :));
            Board(rowIndex,colIndex) = 0; % update board
        else 
            set(hObject, 'FaceColor', playerColours(1, :));
            Board(rowIndex,colIndex) = 1; % update board
        end

    end
end
```

I found this [link](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/495749-capturing-mouse-clicks-on-an-array-patch#answer_427769) and modified the code to be able to expand the board and also select cells that have been turned on already to switch them off.

Now I need a way to extract that `board` value to save the array.

Comment: Saving the board was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74602946/cant-save-data-using-push-button-matlab) if you're wondering!