# Can't save data using push button (MATLAB)

Tags: function, matlab, button, plot, global

I'm trying to create a figure where the user can select cells to turn on or off. Then, the user can click a button 'Enter' to save the board as an array. I successfully found a way to create interactivity in my plot thanks to a very useful explanation I found [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/495749-capturing-mouse-clicks-on-an-array-patch#answer_427769). I just made some changes to suit my needs.

However, I can't find a way to save the board. The button is working (or at least isn't not working), but the data isn't saved. And I don't know how to fix that. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
function CreatePattern
    hFigure = figure;
    hAxes = axes;
    axis equal;
    axis off;
    hold on;

    % create a button to calculate the difference between 2 points
    h = uicontrol('Position',[215 5 150 30],'String','Enter','Callback', @SaveArray);
    
    function SaveArray(ButtonH, eventdata)
        global initial
        initial = Board;
        close(hFigure)
    end

    N = 1; % for line width
    M = 20; % board size
    squareEdgeSize = 1;

    % create the board of patch objects
    hPatchObjects = zeros(M,M);
    for j = M:-1:1
        for k = 1:M
            hPatchObjects(M - j+ 1, k) = rectangle('Position', [k*squareEdgeSize,j*squareEdgeSize,squareEdgeSize,squareEdgeSize], 'FaceColor', [0 0 0],...
                'EdgeColor', 'w', 'LineWidth', N, 'HitTest', 'on', 'ButtonDownFcn', {@OnPatchPressedCallback, M - j+ 1, k});
        end
    end

    %global Board
    Board = zeros(M,M);
    playerColours = [1 1 1; 0 0 0];
    
    xlim([squareEdgeSize M*squareEdgeSize]);
    ylim([squareEdgeSize M*squareEdgeSize]);
    
    function OnPatchPressedCallback(hObject, eventdata, rowIndex, colIndex)
        % change FaceColor to player colour
        
        value = Board(rowIndex,colIndex);
        if value == 1
            set(hObject, 'FaceColor', playerColours(2, :));
            Board(rowIndex,colIndex) = 0; % update board
        else 
            set(hObject, 'FaceColor', playerColours(1, :));
            Board(rowIndex,colIndex) = 1; % update board
        end

    end
end

%imwrite(~pattern,'custom_pattern.jpeg')
```

Comment: So after pressing the button, in the command window, `whos global` does not show "`initial`"? Or does the global variable contain no or unexpected data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround by saving in the workspace AND as a separated file.

```
function SaveArray(ButtonH, eventdata)
        save('Board.mat', 'Board');             % Can be used to simply save your matrix to your current folder with name Board.mat
        assignin('base','BoardVariable',Board)      % Used to simply output your matrix to your working space
        close(hFigure)
end
```

Thank you Footy#8799 on the matlab discord server!